# Make it impossible to undo accepted answer, unless there is a new answer or edit to the original question/answer?

Tags: feature-request, unaccepted-answer

If a certain time has passed since the OP has accepted an answer, let's say a week or two, why can they still undo the accepted answer?

Unless there is a better answer to the question, or an edit to the original question/answer, I find it implausible to be able to unaccept (if that's a word) an answer.

I am saying this because there's a guy/girl who keeps accepting and unaccepting my answer on their question for like 3-4 times already, over a span of two weeks. And there's **no new answer** to their question.

Comment: @Keiwan, not a duplicate, my question is different.  Please read the whole question, not just the first paragraph.

Comment: ^ That being said, repeatedly accepting/unaccepting an answer isn't really okay either. You might want to use a custom moderator flag for this scenario.

Comment: I did read the whole question. Did you read the answers to the question I linked to? More specifically *"If you realise that the currently accepted answer doesn't actually help you then you can remove the acceptance altogether." - ChrisF*

Comment: Since this is your first question on Meta Stack Overflow, I'd like to point out that the downvotes aren't because this is a bad question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (emphasis mine):

> Accepting an answer is *not* meant to be a *definitive and final statement* indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly.

So while the author of a question might think your answer worked, after three weeks they may have found a downside to it and use a solution they found elsewhere. Or the solution might not work anymore on a newer version of the platforms/frameworks involved. Yes, it would be nice if they post that solution as an answer, but the time passed shouldn't prevent them from unaccepting an answer.

However, I agree that the behaviour you describe is annoying. If the user continues to do this, flag the question (or your answer) for ♦ moderator attention, explaining the situation; the moderators may decide to send a private message to the user asking them to stop doing this.

Comment: *The newer version of the platforms/frameworks involved* is what I missed. Thank you :) A flag for moderator attention would solve the issue in my case